# Не хочет обрабатывать события jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, события, click

jquery не хочет обрабатывать события. Не могу понять в чем проблема.

---

```js
$('#mybutton').click(function() {
  alert('Вы нажали на элемент "button"');
});

$('#mybutton').click();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="mybutton">Кнопка</button>
```

Никак не реагирует на событие click у элемента #mybutton

Связи, ссылки везде прописаны. Зато реагирует на событие
$(window).scroll.

Что может быть?

Comment: добавил референс на jQuery  в snippet - все работает

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, JavaScript-код срабатывает раньше, чем успевает загрузиться элемент

```
<button id="mybutton">Кнопка</button>
```

Это весь код или его фрагмент? Попробуйте следующий код, который дожидается загрузки DOM-структуры и лишь затем назначает события

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='ru'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('#mybutton').on('click', function() {
        alert('Вы нажали на элемент "button"');
      });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="mybutton">Кнопка</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#mybutton').click(function() {
        alert('Вы нажали на элемент "button"');
      });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="mybutton">Кнопка</button>
```